# Can't a Filter or Listener use spring beans?

Tags: spring, listener

I have a listener class in `web.xml` like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.datx.monitoring.model.MonitoringHttpSessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And for this class, I have defined a `bean` like this:

```
<bean id="monitoringHttpSessionListener"
    class="com.datx.monitoring.model.MonitoringHttpSessionListener" autowire="byName"/>
```

But this `bean` is not able to use other `beans`. Every time this class is called, it has **null properties**.

This class is the exact same as the other which is working fine. The only difference is, this class is used as a `listener` and the other is not. Why is that?

Comment: I seriously think that, this class is being `new`ed, and it is not related to `spring` at all! If this is confirmed, I may have to modify the question.

Comment: One example for each case is provided at http://www.techper.net/2011/03/05/springified-servlets-listeners-and-filters/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple reason for this: There are two beans. One was created by your web container (which uses `web.xml`) and the other by Spring (which uses your bean definition). The web container and Spring know nothing about each other.

What you need to do is create a normal listener which gets the application context with

```
WebApplicationContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(session.getServletContext());
```

This will allow you to look up beans. Now you can define a bean which the filter can modify.

Note: You will want to give this bean the `request` scope or there will be chaos.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. (with a bit modification to your answer) it is exactly what I needed.